# How to render Date Values on X Axis of LineChart in 2 Lines using JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart, axis, linechart, text-styling

I am using JFreeChart to render a LineChart using CategoryPlot.
Something like:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Daily Revenue",
                "Days", "Revenue", dataset);

        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
```

So as you can understand I must have to display full Time like `23 Feb'18 11:00:00` on the XAxis tilted to 45degrees which I am able to achieve using

```
CategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();
categoryAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
```

But I want to display my text on XAxis in 2 lines somewhat like:

```
23 Feb'18 
11:00:00
```

tilted to 45 degrees. For which I had tried using

```
CategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();         
categoryAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
categoryAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(5);
```

with no success so how can I achieve that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some self-research I found out that while reducing the width and height values of the JFreeChart Image through `ChartUtilities.encodeAsPNG(chart.createBufferedImage(500, 300));` command that the text is getting auto-adjusted to new line.

So after some more research, I got this command that does the work for me. By Creating a Object of `CategoryAxis` along `X-Axis so getDomainAxis()` for `Y-Axis it is getRangeAxis()`

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(0.25f);
```

then we use `.setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(float ratio)` and adjust it as per your requirement!!